# Cassandra : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using cassandra 2.0.8 and getting this exception

```
INFO 16:44:50,132 Initializing system.batchlog
 INFO 16:44:50,138 Initializing system.sstable_activity
 INFO 16:44:50,142 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity/system-sstable_activity-jb-10 (826 bytes)
 INFO 16:44:50,142 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity/system-sstable_activity-jb-9 (827 bytes)
 INFO 16:44:50,142 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity/system-sstable_activity-jb-11 (825 bytes)
 INFO 16:44:50,150 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/system-sstable_activity-KeyCache-b.db
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid3460.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [13378724 bytes in 0.071 secs]
ERROR 16:44:50,333 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:144)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry$Serializer.deserialize(RowIndexEntry.java:120)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.deserialize(CacheService.java:365)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:262)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:421)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:392)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:309)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:266)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:536)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:261)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:144)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowIndexEntry$Serializer.deserialize(RowIndexEntry.java:120)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CacheService$KeyCacheSerializer.deserialize(CacheService.java:365)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:119)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:262)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:421)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:392)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.initCf(Keyspace.java:309)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:266)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:536)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:261)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
Exception encountered during startup: Java heap space
```

Can anyone tell me the reason and solution:

Answer (score 3):

Reach out to cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh location

Check out the current heap size
You can assign at max of 1/2 RAM to the HEAP

```
#MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G" 
#HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

if you are changing your current heap-size then remove comment..

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

Comment: ok i will check that. I check 'commitlogs' firectory and saw that around 250MB total size of files are there ,is that be also a reason?

Comment: I tried with `MAX_HEAP_SIZE="600MB"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="300MB"` but got `Invalid initial heap size: -Xms600MB
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
`

Comment: your machine has 1GB RAM? you can assign 1/2 of RAM of your machine to MAX_HEAP_SIZE, and it has to be HEAP_NEWSIZE="600M" (only M not MB)..

Comment: its 4gb ram. does the size of commit log file is the reason?

Comment: i did this `MAX_HEAP_SIZE="2G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"` but still its same Heap space problem

Comment: Not sure with size of commit log file thing..
but i solved my problems in the past with the above solution only, i would say you have to increase the RAM Size of your system, or else wait for some-one else's to reply for this question.

Comment: if you are using linux then execute the free command before doing any process it will show the available memory-size, so you can get some idea.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible your key cache is taking up too much space (since thats where it died) but it seems unlikely.  You can try to delete your KeyCache before starting

```
/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
```

and set

```
key_cache_size_in_mb: 0
```

in your cassandra.yaml as a test (I would not recommend this permanently) to have it disabled.

You can actually determine whats filling up your heap by opening up the java_pid3460.hprof file it created in yourkit or some heap analyzer to determine whats taking up the space.  There may be something funny going on, very strange to be dying at 13mb or so (size of heap).

Answer (score -3):

Delete all log files in `usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/` and restart Cassandra.

Comment: How would this solve the problem?  Also, wouldn't it just crash Cassandra under circumstances?