# Cassandra: error in Initializing system.sstable activity

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I am getting some problem at cassandra startup. The details of the exceptios is as follows:-

```
INFO  06:49:10 Initializing system.sstable_activity
ERROR 06:49:10 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled Java code
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.writeHeader(CommitLogDescriptor.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:168) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.freshSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) [apache-cassandra-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

What can be the reason for this ?

Comment: I just figured out, it was because of low memory on my system. This memory was being used up because of logs of some other process.

It may also be because of some redundant cache being maintained by cassandra itself .    as shown in this question -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664128/cassandra-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by deleting a commit log that was causing the issue.

I found the log in /casandra/data/commitlog .

After I deleted, I re-ran cassandra and all was well. I hope this helps someone!

Comment: thanks, this solution works fine.. but the real problem is the space on disk, is full!

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what is the reason to this, but restarting my system solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem with commit logs. You should only do this if you don't care about preserving the state of your commit logs.

Try to restart cassandra using

```
sudo systemctl restart cassandra
```

Then I check

```
systemctl status cassandra
```

and see that the status is 'exited' so there is a problem. Check the logs for cassandra using

```
sudo less /var/log/cassandra/system.log

and see org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1498210233635.log
```

Because I don't care about preserving the state of Cassandra I delete all of the commit logs and it now boots up fine

```
sudo rm /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog*
sudo systemctl restart cassandra
```

`systemctl status cassandra` (should confirm that it it now running)